# How to view locally stored HTML files on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I am looking for an option to open html files rather than URLs on the web in the browser on my phone with Ubuntu Touch. As there's no 'open file' option I have been experimenting with file:// type URLs in the address bar but that only results in 'Network Error' messages. Clicking on an html file in the File Manager doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let alone mobile, it's not even possible to open local html files with the "Browser" app in Ubuntu desktop... gives the same "network error" message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write a .desktop file. Read: 
http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-phone%40lists.launchpad.net/msg18884.html

Following the suggestion the asker created a .desktop file in .local/share/applications with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Usage statistics
Type=Application
Exec=webapp-container /home/phablet/Usage/index.html
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

The asker says it does the trick for him. It is not very flexible but suits his needs.